# How to update Array of object and array of object in node js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to update my application which is little bit difficult to update. Schema look like array and object inside array and object

for example schema have a store array inside product array and i want to update product status which is inside store  and inside product array

how i can update these schema any body help thanks in advance.

this is my schema

```
stores: [{
        store_name: String,
        store_category: String,
        bill_image: {type: String},
        total_amount: {type: Number},
        notes: [{description: {type: String}}],
        store_status: {type: Number, default: 0},//0: pending; 1: start pickup; 2: Arrive for pickup
        store_address: {
            address: { type: String },
            title: { type: String },
            lat: { type: String },
            lng: { type: String }
        },
        products: [{
            product_name: { type: String },
            product_image_url: { type: String, default: null },
            product_description: { type: String },
            product_qty: { type: Number },
            product_unit: { type: String },
            procurement_status: { type: String, default: 0 }//0 pending, 1 purchased, 2 unavailable, 3 delivered
        }]
    }]
```

and this is my request

```
{
    booking_id: "30384023808"
    stores : [
        {
            _id:"79734297492394237",
            products: [
                {
                    _id:"53453547457",
                    procurement_status: true
                },
                {
                    _id:"e242235465757",
                    procurement_status: false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id:"56456564434343",
            products: [
                {
                    _id:"6565756756756",
                    procurement_status: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```